# How to resolve the location permission error for Apps on Huawei device?

Tags: geolocation, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-location-kit

Huawei HMS core on my huawei phone do not have defualt permission, I am coding my app using HMS location kit and always got a permission error for Location kit. I followed their development guide to set up the location permission in the Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

And followed their code samples:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    Log.i(TAG, "sdk < 28 Q");
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        String[] strings =
            {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, strings, 1);
    }
} else {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            "android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION") != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        String[] strings = {android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            "android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"};
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, strings, 2);
    }
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The HMS permission must always be allowed. Otherwise, an error will be reported.

   Ensure that the location permission has been assigned to HMS Core (APK). To do so, go to **Settings** > **Apps** > **Apps** and find **HMS Core**. (The menu path may vary depending on the operating system version. If **HMS Core** is not found, tap the menu icon in the upper right corner of **Apps** and tap **Show system processes**.) Then, tap the HMS Core (APK) icon, go to **App info** > **Permissions** > **Location**, and verify that the location permission is assigned to **HMS Core**. On a device running EMUI 10.0 or later, **Location** must be set to **Always** for **HMS Core**.

[image]

2. Ensure that the Location Info switch in the drop-down notification bar is turned on.
3. Simulate Location Requires Impersonation Permission. Otherwise, an error permission error will be reported.

[image]

4. Check whether Location Permission is enabled for your app.

Answer (score 1):

Shirley's answer covers the device side of HMS location permission. To cover this type of scenario for all users with lower EMUI versions that HMS Core does not have location permissions by default, you can use the API "settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(…)" to obtain the device location permission. After that, even the location permission for the HMS Core App was disabled, your app will be able to prompt users to enable related permissions with one-click.

Please refer to [HMS Location guide](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/location-guidev4)

Step 1: Obtain the service API of SettingsClient.

```
SettingsClient settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
```

Step 2: Call checkLocationSettings() to check the device settings.

```
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();

mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);

LocationSettingsRequest locationSettingsRequest = builder.build();

//check Location Settings

settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(locationSettingsRequest)

        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {

            @Override

            public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {

                //Have permissions， send requests

                fusedLocationProviderClient

                        .requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper())

                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {

                            @Override

                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                                //Interface call successfully processed

                            }

                        });

            }

        })

        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {

            @Override

            public void onFailure(Exception e) {

                //Settings do not meet targeting criteria

                int statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();

                switch (statusCode) {

                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:

                        try {

                            ResolvableApiException rae = (ResolvableApiException) e;

                            //Calling startResolutionForResult can pop up a window to prompt the user to open the corresponding permissions

                            rae.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, 0);

                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sie) {

                            //…

                        }

                        break;

                }

            }

        });
```